# Can a subclass access attributes from its superclass in Python?

Tags: python, class

In Python, is it possible for a subclass access attributes from its superclass? Below is a short example code that I would like to make work.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_property_A = some_value
        
    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            self.some_property_B = 0
            if some_property_A == 1:     # <-------- How can I make this line work?
                self.some_property_B = 1
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: B isn't a subclass of A. B is just defined in A's scope, which is strange idea

Comment: Do you mean a subclass or a class defined inside another class's scope?

Comment: You can just use `A.some_propertyA`. Nested classes are so rare, though, that there  was little point in adding a special name to refer to the "containing" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Class B is not your subclass.

Here is the example:

```
# superclass
class Person():
    def __init__(self, per_name, per_age):
        self.name = per_name
        self.age = per_age
 
# subclass      
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, emp_name, emp_age, emp_salary):
        self.salary = emp_salary
        Person.__init__(self, emp_name, emp_age)
        
emp = Employee("John", 20, 8000)  # creating object of superclass
 
print("name:", emp.name, "age:", emp.age, "salary:", emp.salary)
```

This is how you can use variables of Superclass.
For more information visit:

[https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-subclass-of-a-class/#:~:text=All%20the%20attributes%20and%20methods,and%20methods%20of%20the%20superclass](https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-subclass-of-a-class/#:%7E:text=All%20the%20attributes%20and%20methods,and%20methods%20of%20the%20superclass).